# GridLayoutManager resizes the first item on the row above the last one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` that's using `GridLayoutManager`. It has some strange behaviour when the `itemCount` is not divided by the `spanCount`. It appears to resize the first item on the row above the last one (See [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xqfF.png)).

If the `itemCount` is divided by the `spanCount`, then it is looking good (See [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lSZU.png)).

Do you have some ideas?

If more context is needed, I can provide it, just let me know. Thank you!

Using `StaggeredGridLayout` will work as intended, but this is not an option for the project I'm working at.